# Jqgrid pagination is not working

Tags: jquery, pagination, jqgrid

Pagination is not working for me.. in this if add `loadonce:true`, means multifilter is not working.. How can I work my pagination? Help me.

```
jQuery("#displayparticipants").jqGrid({
    loadtext : sLoadText,
    align:"center",
    headertitles: true,
    url: jsonUrl,
    editurl: editUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "post",
    postData: pdata,
    colNames : jQuery.parseJSON(colNames),
    colModel: jQuery.parseJSON(colModels),
    direction: $('html').attr('dir'),
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    loadonce: false,
    gridview: true,             
    rowNum: 10,        
    scrollOffset:0,
    autowidth: autowidth,
    sortable : true,
    sortname: 'firstname',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords : true,
    rowList: [10,25,50,100,250,500,1000,2500,5000],
    multiselect: true,
    hoverrows: true, // true by default, 
                     // can be switched to false if highlight on hover is not needed
```

Comment: The pagination adds extra parameters ("page" and "rows") to the query string when calling your "jsonUrl" - are you picking these up on the back end to control the data returned?

Comment: Which "multifilter" you mean? Please, include in all questions about jqGrid the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). In general `loadonce: true` scenario is recommended if need to load not many rows (less then 1000, for example). If you don't use `loadonce: true`, then you have to implement paging, sorting and optionally filtering/searching in your **server side** code.

Comment: in my pagination when [loadonce:false], in pagination total number of pages is always showing as '0'.